# Do I need to create domain and infrastructure layers in this application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture, cloud, software-design

I am brand new to the concept of software architecture. I am creating a relatively simple application that is mostly CRUD, written in C#. Because my application is mostly CRUD, I have designed my app to have a data model at its core. [Here is a diagram depicting what I have right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATrTy.png)

Basically, my app is split up into four layers:

A Data layer that holds my entities and EF Core DbContext. (No abstraction over EF Core at the moment) My entities represent both records in a database and files in cloud storage.

A Service layer for functionality that would be needed by multiple features. (This includes things like a PasswordService for hashing, salting and verifying passwords, and a FileService that performs CRUD on files in cloud storage)

A Business Logic Layer that is composed of feature folders. Using MediatR, each folder will have an input, some work that will require EFCore and maybe a service, and an output.

A UI layer composed of the UI for each slice of functionality. Using Razor pages, each page will send a request to the Business Logic Layer, and use the output to build the UI.

**It appears to me that in my app's current state, the data layer is dependent on the service layer.** I say this because the password hash and salts in the my user entity wouldn't work unless you had the PasswordService, and I have entities that represent files in cloud storage that wouldn't be possible unless you had the FileService.

**Does this mean I need to restructure my app?**

**I think that I do, and I have a solution:**

Create a domain layer that has the entities, and an interface for how they are persisted, like an IUnitOfWork. The IUnitOfWork would represent CRUD operations on both records in the database and files in cloud storage.

Create an infrastructure layer that has the implementation of the domain's IUnitOfWork. In its implementation I would have my EF Core DbContext and something to manage files on cloud storage, like an abstraction of an S3 bucket or maybe my own custom cloud storage service.

Note: This is just a personal project that won't really matter in the end, but I am trying to learn good architecure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Generalities on software architecture

The most important part about software architecture is that there is no good or bad architecture, only good or bad implementations of an architecture (i.e. whether the developers did violate the architecture or not). The architecture itself is a response to functional and non-functional constraints and context, present and *expected*, and an architecture can be effective or ineffective in that regard. This is why I don't think that is possible to learn "good architecture" on a personal project that "won't really matter in the end", because you precisely don't have a context or constraints to adapt to.

Conceptually, the more layers you add in your application, the more complex it becomes and the harder it is to maintain. Also adding layers usually means adding different level of details / representations of concepts, which require additional computational power for model projection and translation. The cost of additional layers are only worth it if it solves strong problems, such as security, or by allowing different teams to scale development.

For learning purposes, you might want to fork your codebase, try your refactor and compare what are the pros and cons for each, especially those you didn't expect. This will provide you with a practical experience that will help you take decisions on other projects, as well as to anticipate consequences of your decisions, which is a critical skill to master for a good software architect.

## Should you refactor

> It appears to me that in my app's current state, the data layer is dependent on the service layer. Does this mean I need to restructure my app?

No, it doesn't. Or rather should I say: it doesn't **unless you can explain how it goes against your architectural objectives**. Which in turns asks the questions of what your constraints are, and what it is you try to achieve "architecturally" speaking. Without that, there is no reason to change, and there is no way to evaluate whether the target architecture is "better" or "worse" regarding it's effectiveness to achieve your objectives.

## Advices on your architecture

My general piece of advice on app architecture: keep it as simple as possible, it's usually cheaper to maintain and more efficient to operate. Or as designers say: less is more! Only go for complex structure if you can't avoid them.

I think most developers over-architect their applications, especially vertically (layering UI / Domain / data) and not enough horizontally (code from different features in different folders / assembly). This is reason #1 for why applications eventually become spaghettis IMO.

Technologies used to persist DB records are not designed to store files and vice-versa. Make sure you can change your file persistence backend without the need to refactor your EF layer and vice-versa. Also keep in mind that perhaps all your features does not require the same kind of persistance technology: 5400RPM HDD for large and cold files, .M2 SSD with additional memory cache for small hot files. Also consider the difference in latency and availability of cloud vs on-premises storage. The same applies for db records whether relational or non-relational document-based or key-value store.

The Repository / Unit of work pattern is a nice mean of decoupling the data access layer from the business and presentation layer. This is useful in DDD context where persistence might have very different structure than the domain, and you have different people working on each part. You can define a border and unit test separately. Then do some integration testing. But if you're in a one-man project with limited business rules and a very CRUD oriented service, perhaps you can assume a more cohesive pattern ?